# How to repeat request in Play! framework 2.1?

Tags: scala, playframework, request, akka, playframework-2.1

Is there any simple way to repeat request until getting success result in Play2.1 (scala)? And how to limit the number of attempts?

I want to do something like this:

```
WS.url("some.url").get().map{ response =>
  val strval = someFunction(response)
  strval match {
    case "success" => println("do something after successful request")
    case "error" => println("repeat same request until success - and repeat maximum N times!")
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

*Untested*

You could do something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

def withRetry[T](retries:Int = 5)(f: => Future[T]) = 
  f.recoverWith {
    case t:Throwable if (retries > 0) => withRetry(retries - 1)(f)
  }
```

And then in your own code you could use it like this:

```
withRetry(retries = 2) {
  WS.url("some.url").get
    .map { response =>
      require(someFunction(response) != "error", "Please retry")
      response
    }
}
```

If you are willing to rewrite the `someFunction` to a `Response => Boolean` you could use it like this:

```
def someFunction(r: Response): Boolean = ???

withRetry(retries = 2) {
  WS.url("some.url").get
    .filter(someFunction)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, EECOLOR! It looks good, but I'm a little confused with using Await since it generally blocks a thread pool.

Comment: @krispo I don't know Scala handles this. The `Await` object states: 'Although this method is blocking, the internal use of `blocking` ensures that the underlying `ExecutionContext` is prepared to properly manage the blocking.' Interesting point though!

Comment: why do you need the Await within a future? why not just do `f.recoverWith`?

Comment: if it's just to implement a timeout, you could pass in the recursion a `scala.concurrent.duration.Deadline` and, in the same way you test for the retries counter, test `deadline.hasTimeLeft`. This would make the whole thing non blocking.

Comment: @Mortimer I do not understand, how would that timeout the passed in (possibly eternal) future `f`?

Comment: You will have to eventually await for the future; you are returning a future that will have to be resolved in that way at some time. I am just saying that you do not have to do the awaiting there.
Your code would retry a number of times in case of a never returning web service, in addition to retrying in case of an error. I am not saying it's wrong. But it might not be what is wanted, and if the web service is dead or under heavy load, you might not want to retry every 1 second in case of timeouts. If it was me, I would separate the retry in case of "error" and the never responding webservice.

Comment: Ahh yes, I totally agree. I don't know how I got into my head that there was a timeout required. I edited my answer to remove the timeout. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def wSCall = WS.url("http://foo/bar").get()

def ƒ(response: Response, n: Int): Result = {
  val strval = someFunction(response)

  strval match {
    case "success" => Ok("Ok!")
    case "error"   => {
      if (n > 0)
        Async { wSCall.map(response => ƒ(response, n - 1)) }
      else
        BadRequest("Fail :(")
    }
  }
}

Async { wSCall.map(response => ƒ(response, 10)) }
```

Comment: Thanks, Samy! I like it and would see later.

Comment: @krispo: So, how did my answer help?